# PHP source build on windows: Files: no such file or directory

Tags: php, nmake

Foowlowing the tutorial at https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild. Doing this for PHP 7,  I get all the way to the **nmake** command.

When I run nmake I get the following errors

```
    "" -h win32\ -r C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc14\x86\php-src\Release_TS\ -x C:\php
-sdk\phpdev\vc14\x86\php-src\Release_TS\ win32\build\wsyslog.mc
'-h' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"' : return code '0x1'
```

The Release_TS folder has a win32 foler, but it is empty. Is the source supposed to have something in there?

Answer (score 2):

Had to use a specific command prompt

Visual Studio 2015-> VS2015 x64 x86 Cross Tools Command Prompt.
you have to find the right combo for what you are building php for (x86/x64) with you are building on (x86/x64).